# SQL Dedupped in CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have three CTEs which run perfectly and give me a complete list of what I am asking but in the final results there are multiple dups, due to the fax_date having time and date in it when exporting . I want to dedup the list by Auth_Number so I can remove Dups . Basically I want a line for every unique Auth_Num with all its detail. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
With

Memb AS (
Select Distinct 
mbc.Hsc_Id                          AS  Auth_Number,
mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD                   AS Policy_State,
mb.fst_nm                           AS Member_First_Name,
mb.lst_nm                           AS Member_last_name,
mb.mbr_id                           AS Member_Id
From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
Left Join icue.hsc hs
On mbc.Hsc_Id  = hs.hsc_id
Left Join icue.mbr mb
On hs.mbr_id = mb.mbr_id 
Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'PA' 
And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9'
Union 
Select Distinct 
mbc.hsc_id                         AS Auth_Number,
mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD                  AS Policy_State,
mb.fst_nm                          AS Member_First_Name,
mb.lst_nm                          AS Member_last_name,
mb.mbr_id                          AS Member_Id
From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
Left Join icue.hsc hs
On mbc.Hsc_Id  = hs.hsc_id
Left Join icue.mbr mb
On hs.mbr_id = mb.mbr_id
Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'NJ' 
And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')
),


  Fax_Sent AS( 
SELECT Distinct
mbc.*,
cmt.CNTC_NM                     As Provider_Name,
cmt.FAX_NBR                     AS Fax_Number,
cmt.hsc_id                      AS Auth_num,
CASE When cmt.FAX_NBR ='201-553-7889' THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END  AS Fax_Sent
From Memb mbc
Left Join icue.cmnct_trans cmt
On mbc.Auth_Number = cmt.hsc_id
Where cmt.CNTC_NM ='CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA'),


Letter_Sent AS(  
Select Distinct
cmt.*,
act.Actv_strt_dttm                       AS Fax_Date,
CASE When ACTV_TYP_ID ='5' THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END  AS Letter_Sent 
From Fax_Sent cmt
Left Join icue.actv act
On cmt.Auth_num = act.hsc_id
Where trunc(act.actv_strt_dttm) between to_date('19-FEB-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('06-MAR-2018','DD-MON-YYYY')       
)
```

Comment: When you do have multiple dates - which should be used? notionally you want to 'group by' + aggregations, but you would have to tell us what aggregation / rule to use for every field other than Auth_Num

Comment: If you don't need time component of `fax_date` value, could you `TRUNC` it and get rid of multiple lines?

Comment: Have a look at `ROW_NUMBER`, when you `PARTITION BY Auth_Number` and apply some order you should get what you want.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks!  I did as you said and got the results I want . I will be putting my final code in the answer. THANK YOU !!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone ! I did do the row_number function on Auth_Number and I was able to dedup my list. I also added an desc for the column and dedup off of the "DP" Column in the final CTE.

```
Letter_Sent AS(  
Select Distinct
cmt.*,
TRUNC(act.actv_strt_dttm)                       AS Fax_Date,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY cmt.Auth_num ORDER BY act.actv_strt_dttm,TRUNC(act.actv_strt_dttm)DESC)DP,
CASE When act.ACTV_TYP_ID ='5' THEN 'Yes'---"Manual letter sent "
ELSE 'No'
END  AS Letter_Sent 
From Fax_Sent cmt
Left Join icue.actv act
On cmt.Auth_num = act.hsc_id
Where trunc(act.actv_strt_dttm) between to_date('19-FEB-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('06-MAR-2018','DD-MON-YYYY')
)
Select * From Letter_Sent Where DP = '1'
```